# C# Deserialize an XML array containing another array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, serialization

I've got an xml I'd like to deserialize to classes

```
<MAINELEMENT>
  <ARRAY1>
    <ARRAY2 Array2Attr="Array2Attr">
      <ARRAY2ITEM Array2ItemAttr="Array2ItemAttr">Value</ARRAY2ITEM>
      <ARRAY2ITEM Array2ItemAttr="Array2ItemAttr">Value</ARRAY2ITEM>
      <ARRAY2ITEM Array2ItemAttr="Array2ItemAttr">Value</ARRAY2ITEM>
      <ARRAY2ITEM Array2ItemAttr="Array2ItemAttr">Value</ARRAY2ITEM>
    </ARRAY2>
    <ARRAY2 Array2Attr="Array2Attr">
      <ARRAY2ITEM Array2ItemAttr="Array2ItemAttr">Value</ARRAY2ITEM>
    </ARRAY2>
  </ARRAY1>
</MAINELEMENT>
```

Here is my code, and the problem is that Array2Items becomes null.
Obviously, class Array2 should be an array instead of containing one. How can I do that?

```
    [XmlRoot("MAINELEMENT")]
    public class MainElement
    {
        [XmlArray("ARRAY1")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ARRAY2", Type = typeof(Array2))]
        public Array2[] Array2s { get; set; }

        public MainElement()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Array2
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Array2Attr")] public string Array2Attr { get; set; }
        [XmlArrayItem("ARRAY2ITEM", Type = typeof(Array2Item))]
        public Array2Item[] Array2Items { get; set; }

        public Array2()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Array2Item
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Array2ItemAttr")] public string Array2ItemAttr { get; set; }
        [XmlText] public string Value { get; set; }

        public Array2Item()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainElement));
            MainElement mainElement = (MainElement)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("MAINELEMENT")]
    public class MainElement
    {
        [XmlArray("ARRAY1")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ARRAY2")]
        public Array2[] Array2s { get; set; }

    }

    public class Array2
    {
        [XmlElement("ARRAY2ITEM")]
        public Array2Item[] Array2Items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Array2Item
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Array2ItemAttr { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Miraculously, it worked! It took me a while till I found your key modification. And now I still don't get it, how [XmlElement("ARRAY2ITEM")] could desctibe an array.

Comment: The default tags for an array is two tags parent and child.  Using XmlElement changes the array to use only one tag.